# How to send data from one component to another component and populate its fields in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8

I am working on a project which has 2 components one is AddProductComponent and the other is Product List Component.
what I want to do is when I click on the edit product button in ProductListComponent I should be redirected to the Add product component and the addproductform is populated by the details of the specific product I created. I am not able to do so.the data I am receiving is from a serverside REST APIs

I want to know how can I send data from one component to another component and populate that component.
**Note - both the components are at the same level i.e. there is NO parent-child hierarchy between components**

Comment: please provide some code, to be able to understand

Answer (score 0):

you can Pass data something like this...

```
clickeditproduct(){

this.route.navigate(['/addproduct', JSON.stringify(Passdata)]);

}
or 
const addProducts = JSON.parse(this.dataRoute.snapshot.params['Passdata']);
```